# Orderby Date and Category

Tags: wp-query

Query and order by date, or query and order by category is no problem, but is there anyway to order by date and category?

So if I query 30 Events (CPT), there might be 5 events per day so I want them ordered by date, but within each day, "premium" (term, custom tax)would show before "standard" (second term) on each day.

Result would look something like this:

Oct 1

- event (premium)
- event (standard)
- event (standard)
- event (standard)

Oct 2

- event (premium)
- event (premium)
- event (premium)
- event (standard)

Oct 3

- event (premium)
- event (premium)
- event (standard)
- event (standard)

Comment: `usort()` is about the only sane thing I can think of here with your current setup. From the back, I would rather have used custom fields ;-)

Comment: Since when is order by category no problem? WP doesn't like ordering by terms, it's pain. How exactly you are doing that for starters?

Comment: @PieterGoosen, I am using a custom field for the Event Date. Not sure how that helps.

Comment: @Rarst, you're totally right. Sorry, having a hard time coming up with a place to start other than doing 2 queries per day - one query per term.

Comment: Custom fields aren't the issue, terms are... You might be better of just querying everything and re-sorting with custom PHP code.

Comment: @Rarst exactly what I said, use `usort()` to resort post according to terms, would have been better to had the terms as custom field values. ;-)